# Econometric model for TFP

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth

I want to model TFP series using an econometric model, be it AR(1) process, unit root with drift drift process etc. I was wondering if anyone knows of published papers discussing various methods of modelling technical progress. Alternatively, type in your model of TFP.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the article:

Olley, G. Steven, and Ariel Pakes. [The dynamics of productivity in the telecommunications equipment industry](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2171831).

This is an Econometrica paper (1996). It is the standard method to estimate productivity nowadays.